# /bin/sh: Unknown: command not found - when running make

Tags: reactjs, bash, react-native, makefile, gnu-make

This is what's in my makefile inside our React project in the frontend directory:

```
default: tester

.PHONY: prty
prty:
    `npm bin`/prettier --write .
```

However, when I run `make`, I get

```
/bin/sh: Unknown: command not found
make: *** [fmt] Error 127
```

I am not really sure why it's doing that. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Make is running this command in the shell:

```
`npm bin`/prettier --write .
```

The backticks in the shell run the command inside and replace the backticks with the output.  Apparently the output of running the command `npm bin` on that system is a string that begins with the word `Unknown` so the shell tries to run the command:

```
Unknown something something/prettier --write .
```

and since `Unknown` is not a valid shell command, you get the results you see.

If you just run:

```
npm bin
```

instead you'll see the full error message.

Comment: Great explanation. But would this error message not be printed to stderr, which is not caught by the backticks? In this case, the full error message should be displayed, and since `npm bin` would have empty stdout and the command to be executed should be `/prettier --write`.

Comment: Since we have no idea where the message is coming from or what it actually says, we can't say.  Maybe `npm` is writing a message that starts with `Unknown`, to stdout.